# Test calling of an external script run via Popen that expects no available data in stdin using pytest

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I have an external tool with a command line interface that checks whether any data is provided via stdin by using `sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]` and adjusts the expected parameters accordingly. I call this external tool via `subprocess` and rely on the use case where there is no input provided via stdin.

Now I want to run an automated integration test on this functionality via `pytest`. But I cannot get it to work without providing the `pytest` command line option `--capture=sys` disabling capturing on file descriptor level for all tests. In any other case (also when using `capfd.disabled()` or `capsys.disabled()` around the call within the test as these only disable stdout and stderr but not stdin capture), the external tool detects that there would be input provided via stdin, triggering the incorrect conclusions about other parameters and thus causing my test to fail.

For the sake of an example, I basically have something like the following files:

external_script.py:

```
import select
import sys

print(sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0])
if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
    print(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
print(sys.argv)
```

internal_part.py:

```
import subprocess

def call_external():
    popen = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python3", "external_script.py", "1"],
                             stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(popen.communicate()[:2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_external()
```

test.py:

```
import internal_part

def test(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():  # or capfd.disabled()
        internal_part.call_external()
```

When I now run internal_part.py via python, I get the expected output, that `sys.stdin` is not returned by the call to `select.select` and thus that no input is available in stdin. But when I run `test.py` via `pytest` without `--capture=sys`, I get output indicating that data was provided via stdin. Reading from sys.stdin then gives an empty string.

If the `select.select` call where within the internal part, I at least would get an error that this is an unsupported operation of the pseudofile being the redirected stdin. For the external tool, running in its own interpreter, I don't get any indication that something went wrong except that erroneously stdin is detected to provide input.

Is there any option to get this test scenario to work, e.g. by disabling the capture of stdin for this specific test, without disabling the capture on the file descriptor level for all my tests in that test suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to generate and explicitly pass a file descriptor that is not ready for reading in the production code<sup>1</sup>, you can generate a new named pipe via `os.pipe` and pass its reading end as stdin. Obviously, it is somewhat of a workaround for the strange interface to generate a new pipe with the sole purpose of it being empty. But as long as you don't write anything into the pipe, the pipe should not be ready for reading and thus the `select.select` call should not pick it up. The internal part could then look somewhat like the code below:

```
import contextlib
import os
import subprocess

@contextlib.contextmanager
def not_ready_to_read():
    try:
        read_end, write_end = os.pipe()
        yield read_end
    finally:
        os.close(read_end)
        os.close(write_end)

def call_external():
    with not_ready_to_read() as not_ready_stdin:
        popen = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python3", "external_script.py", "1"],
                                 stdin=not_ready_stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        print(popen.communicate()[:2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_external()
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This can also help you with other situations where the test via `select.select` erroneously suggests that some data is passed via stdin, such as if you run the script via the `slurm` job scheduler. Therefore, it's not an adaption of the production code with the sole purpose of enabling the test.