# Running a subprocess fails when not using pytest no-capture

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

### Setup

I've simplified the problem to the core:

1. Having pytest installed

```sh
pip install pytest==5.4.3
```

2. Having a shell script

```sh
# has-stdin.sh

# Detect stdin
if [[ ! -t 0 ]]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

3. Having a Python test

```py
# test.py

import subprocess
import unittest


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        process = subprocess.run(
            ["sh", "./has-stdin.sh"],
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            check=True,
            shell=False
        )
        assert process.stdout.decode("utf-8") == "no\n"
```

---

### Testing

✅ Script works in a bash shell

```
$ sh ./has-stdin.sh
no
```

```
$ echo '' | sh ./has-stdin.sh
yes
```

```
$ sh ./has-stdin.sh <<< ''
yes
```

✅ Runs successfully with `-s` (e.g. `--capture=no`)

```
$ pytest test.py -s
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/maikel/docker/library/postgresql
collected 1 item

test.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.02s ===========================
```

❌ Runs unsuccessfully without `-s`

```
$ pytest test.py
========================== test session starts ==========================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/maikel/docker/library/postgresql
collected 1 item

test.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]

================================ FAILURES ===============================
_____________________________ TestCase.test _____________________________

self = <test.TestCase testMethod=test>

    def test(self):
        process = subprocess.run(
            ["sh", "./has-stdin.sh"],
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            check=True,
            shell=False
        )
>       assert process.stdout.decode("utf-8") == "no\n"
E       AssertionError: assert 'yes\n' == 'no\n'
E         - no
E         + yes

test.py:23: AssertionError
======================== short test summary info ========================
FAILED test.py::TestCase::test - AssertionError: assert 'yes\n' == 'no\n'
=========================== 1 failed in 0.10s ===========================
```

---

What is making the difference in using `-s`? How to run this pytest successfully without `-s`?

I've tried [Test calling of an external script run via Popen that expects no available data in stdin using pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768797/test-calling-of-an-external-script-run-via-popen-that-expects-no-available-data), but when using that method both `pytest` commands fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pip install ptyprocess==0.6.0
```

```py
# test.py

import unittest

from ptyprocess import PtyProcess


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        process = PtyProcess.spawn(
            ["sh", "./has-stdin.sh"]
        )
        process.wait()
        output = process.read().decode("utf-8")
        if process.exitstatus:
            raise Exception(output.strip("\r\n"))
        assert output.strip("\r\n") == 'no'
```

---

✅ Runs successfully with `-s`:

```
$ pytest test.py -s
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/maikel/docker/library/postgresql
collected 1 item

test.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.60s ===========================
```

✅ Runs successfully without `-s`:

```
$ pytest test.py
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/maikel/docker/library/postgresql
collected 1 item

test.py .

=========================== 1 passed in 0.60s ===========================
```

---

#### Caveats

- It runs quite a bit slower than `subprocess` (0.60s vs 0.02s in this example)
- There is no distinction between `stdout` and `stderr`

---

The situation is explained by this diagram:

[image: pty-diagram]

Source: https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/3931cd4/docs/index.rst

Answer (score 3):

That's a very interesting problem.

I got so intrigued so I did run the code locally and examined what's happening:

In the first case (running `without -s`) the shell's `/proc/self/fd/0` is `/dev/null` but running `with -s` the shell's `/proc/self/fd/0` is `/dev/pts/7` in my case.

```
$ pgrep -f has-st
12727
$ ls -la  /proc/12727/fd/0 
lrwx------ 1 quoyn quoyn 64 Aug  4 00:13 /proc/12727/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/7
```

and

```
$ pgrep -f has-st
12793
$ ls -la  /proc/12793/fd/0 
lr-x------ 1 quoyn quoyn 64 Aug  4 00:17 /proc/12793/fd/0 -> /dev/null
```

This si because when you run with "-s" pytest **does not capture** the terminal and simply passes it through, that's why it is `/dev/pts/7`. If I run `ls -l /proc/self/fd/0` in my terminal after pytest has quit I indeed get:

```
lrwx------ 1 quoyn quoyn 64 Aug  4 00:29 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/7
```

You can try **without pytest** as well, only python:

```
import subprocess
s = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/proc/self/fd/0"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=None, check=True, shell=False)
print(s.stdout)
```

And try executing as `python code_above.py` and `echo '' | python code_above.py`

EDIT:

And to answer the second question

> How to run this pytest successfully without -s?

Use a pseudo terminal yourself. Run the subprocess in a [pty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html).\

EDIT2:

The mimimal test to reproduce/demonstrate this problem, run the following code as `pytest test.py` and `pytest -s test.py`:

```
import sys
def test():
    assert sys.stdin.isatty()
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction you pushed me.  I dived into `pty` and found the `ptyprocess` which does what I need.